# SSH hot to check remote directory exist

Tags: bash, ssh, directory

Idea is to check remote folder. Is it exist or no?
I try this

> ssh -p 22 -tt user@server.com  'bash -d /home/test22

and it works fine

> /home/test22: /home/test22: is a directory 
>   Connection to server.com closed.

But when I try to use it with "IF" - it is wrong...always said "That directory exists"

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "ssh -p 22 -tt user@server.com  'bash -d /home/test22'" ]; then
    echo "That directory exists"
else
    echo "That directory doesn't exists"
fi
```

Can you show correct example?

Thank you!

Comment: That reply looks like an error message, not like a "result". Such error is written to `stdout`, the error output. I do nto see how you want to use that in a conditional. You might want to take a look at the `file` command. There is a `man page` for the command, as always.

Comment: I just want to check remote directory and run depended condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if dir exist over ssh and return results to host machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927911/how-to-check-if-dir-exist-over-ssh-and-return-results-to-host-machine)

Comment: #!/bin/bash
 
if [ ssh -p 22 -tt user@com  '[ -d /home/test22]' ]; then
    echo "That directory exists"
else
    echo "That directory doesn't exists"
fi   ----------------- like answer : -bash: [: too many arguments

Answer (score 4):

The command to use is not `bash` but `test` or its alias `[`:

```
if ssh -p 22 -tt user@server.com  'test -d /home/test22'; then
    echo "That directory exists"
else
    echo "That directory doesn't exists"
fi
```

The other important thing is that `[]` is not part of the `if` syntax. `if` is always followed by a command and `if` evaluates its exit status. So no need to surround your `ssh` command with `[]`.

`-d dir` are actually the arguments of command `test` or `[`.

```
test -d dir
[ -d dir ]
```

are identical, the latter form requires a closing `]` argument.