# Check if directory exists on remote machine with ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

This question has been already posted but I would like to know if there is a way to know if a directory exists on a remote machine with ssh BUT from the command line directly and not from a script. As I saw in this previous post: [How to check if dir exists over ssh and return results to host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927911/how-to-check-if-dir-exist-over-ssh-and-return-results-to-host-machine), I tried to write in the command line the following:

```
ssh armand@127.0.0.1 '[ -d Documents ]'
```

But this does not print anything. I would like to know if there's a way to display an answer easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a one liner:

```
ssh armand@127.0.0.1 '[ -d Documents ] && echo exists || echo does not exist'
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Though that suffers from my first mistake where it will print "does not exist" even if it does exist and the ssh fails for some reason

Answer (score 4):

That command will just return whether or not the `Documents` directory exists, you can extend the answer in the linked question to do something if it does like:

```
if ssh armand@127.0.0.1 '[ -d Documents ]'; then
    printf "There is a Documents directory\n"
else
    printf "It does not exist, or I failed to check at all\n"
fi
```

or if you want to store whether or not it exists in a variable you could do something like

```
ssh armand@127.0.0.1 '[ -d Documents ]'
is_a_directory=$?
```

now if `is_a_directory` contains `0` you know there is a `Documents` directory, otherwise there is not such a directory or we failed to `ssh` and find out

Comment: Techinically, this will print "It does not exist" even if the directory exists but the connection attempt fails for some reason.

Comment: But there is no way to catch from this command a variable such a boolean to know if this exists ? I actually want to run this command from a python script and this would be much easier. Thanks !

Comment: `-d` isn't really for existence, and the result could be "exist but not directory". More granular control: `ssh user@host 'function exist_and_is_dir { [[ -d $1 ]] && echo "exists and is directory" || { [[ -e $1 ]] && echo "exists but is not directory" || echo "does not exist"; }; }; exist_and_is_dir Downloads`.

Comment: @hackchoc If you just `ssh armand@127.0.0.1 '[ -d Documents ]'`, assuming `ssh` is successful then the return code is either 0 or 1, where 0 is for exists and is a directory, and 1 is for anything else. So use `subprocess.check_call` to raise an exception when it returns 1.

Comment: @hackchoc I updated the answer to show storing the answer in a variable

Comment: @hackchoc: the "variable" will be the exit status of `ssh`: 0 if it exists, 1 if it's not a directory, 255 if ssh failed

Comment: Great, thank you all for your help and your contribution ! :)